How to stream Transcribe Medical using the Java SDK?
AWS has a code example here: (under Streaming Transcriptions -> Java)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/getting-started-sdk.html
I have taken that code example (which works perfectly) and tried to adapt it to use AWS Transcribe Medical instead. I made the following changes:
client.startStreamTranscription(...)

into
client.startMedicalStreamTranscription(...)


    private static StartStreamTranscriptionRequest getRequest(Integer mediaSampleRateHertz) {
    return StartStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
            .languageCode(LanguageCode.EN_US.toString())
            .mediaEncoding(MediaEncoding.PCM)
            .mediaSampleRateHertz(mediaSampleRateHertz)
            .build();
}

into
  private static StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionRequest getRequest(Integer mediaSampleRateHertz) {
    return StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
            .languageCode(LanguageCode.EN_US.toString())
            .mediaEncoding(MediaEncoding.PCM)
            .mediaSampleRateHertz(mediaSampleRateHertz)
            .specialty(Specialty.PRIMARYCARE)
            .type(Type.CONVERSATION)
            .build();
}


private static StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler getResponseHandler() {
    return StartStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler.builder()

into
private static StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler getResponseHandler() {
    return StartMedicalStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler.builder()


Absolutely nothing seems to work as I get the following error in a loop:
23:26:16.755 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-2] WARN io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise -- An exception was thrown by software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerSubscriber$2.operationComplete()

This cannot stem from an authorization issue as my profile is setup with AwsTranscribeFullAccess which includes Transcribe Medical.
Any ideas?
